# Issues with serving files only in Karma

Tags: extjs4, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

I am trying to set up Karma to run a suite of Jasmine tests as part of a Maven build. I have set up Maven to run Karma via Node, but am struggling to get the files I need to be able to run my application served correctly by Karma. My application is an ExtJS 4 application, which brings its own issues of course, but I think there is something not working as expected in the Karma config itself.

I have tried to set up my Karma config to include only certain files, and serve the rest, so that it doesn't automatically execute everything, but the application has access to  the files it needs. The [Karma files documentation] suggests that the `included` parameter will include the file in the page within a `<script>` tag, where the `served` parameter will serve the files. What I actually see is that if I include files (`included: true`), they will be served, but if I only wish to serve them (`included: false, served: true`) they are not served.

For example:

```
            { pattern: 'app/**/*.js', included: false, served: true, watched: false },
            { pattern: 'app-test/specs/**/*.js', watched: true, included: true},
```

results in the .js specs in subdirectories of the app-test/specs/ directory are run, but the source files in app/ are not even served. I have confirmed this by opening the developer tools in Chrome and looking at the sources to see which files have been served by Karma.

I expect my source files to be served and available to my application, without necessarily being included. This is important for sources that are overridden by test config, as they must not be executed before any test overrides are in place.